# Have HTML5 video reset itself to beginning after it plays through?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, html5-video

Is there a way to have a HTML5 video reset itself to the beginning after it plays through? Will be displaying the video through Safari on an iPad primarily.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `loop` attribute in your `<video>` tag.

```
<video loop>
 <source src="something.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great, but we want it to go back to the beginning and show the image poster so that someone else can come along and hit play. We don't want it to keep looping.

Comment: Then you'd need some javascript